# How to implement manually JPA relation OneToMany

Tags: database, jpa, jpa-2.0, entity-relationship

I am using JPA annotations and when i have relation OneToMany - ManyToOne, when i see my entity in the ManyToOne, the joinColumn is always with null value.

Next i will show my example, i have **Product**:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "PC_PRODUCT")

  public class Product extends LaunchEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @XmlElement(name = "Product_Name", required = true)
  protected String productName;

  @XmlElement(name = "Product_Description")
  protected String productDescription;

  @XmlElement(name = "Product_To_Charge")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
  protected List<ChargeRelation> productToCharge;
```

And, this is my ChargeRelation class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PC_CHARGE_RELATION")
public class ChargeRelation
    extends RelationEntity
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "Charge", required = true)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    protected Charge charge;

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    protected Product product;
```

I am reading a xml file, convert data for a string, make unmarshall for my root object and persist this object.

The problem is when i found a charge relation in my string, the values are inserted on the **charge relation table** but the **column with the product_id is always null**.

I have all setters and getters defined. How i can force this to make the manual insert? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) has an extension called `@XmlInverseReference` that allows you to map the back-pointer.

**Product**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PC_PRODUCT")
public class Product extends LaunchEntity {

    @XmlElement(name = "Product_To_Charge")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    protected List<ChargeRelation> productToCharge;

}
```

**ChargeRelation**

The `@XmlInverseReference` annotation is used where you previously had `@XmlTransient`.  `@XmlInverseReference` acts like `@XmlTransient` during the marshal operation, and will populate the back-pointer during an unmarshal operation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PC_CHARGE_RELATION")
public class ChargeRelation extends RelationEntity {

    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "productToCharge")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    protected Product product;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: i try it but didn't work. i make a recursive method to make all relations. now it's working :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that JPA provider reflects the state of many-to-one side of relationship when saving it to the database.

However, JAXB only populates one-to-many side during XML unmarshalling, therefore you need to populate many-to-one side manually after unmarshalling.